# Proving the existence of a sequence with recursive growth constraints

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, recurrence-relations

Fix $0 < c < 1/3$. Show that there exists a strictly increasing sequence $a_k > 0$, a sequence $b_k \geq 0$, and an infinite set $K \subseteq \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ such that 
\begin{align}\label{1}\tag{1}
\begin{array}{ll}
b_k = 2c a_k - 100 \log a_k > 0 & \text{ if } k \in K \\
b_k = 0 & \text{ otherwise }
\end{array}
\end{align}
\begin{align}\label{2}\tag{2}
c a_{k} + 100 \log a_k > 2k + 2\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} b_i  \quad \text{ if } k \in K
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\label{3}\tag{3}
a_k > a_{k-1} + \log a_{k-1} + b_k \quad \text{ for all large } k \\
\label{4}\tag{4}
a_k < (1-2c)^{-1} \left( a_{k-1} - \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} b_i \right)\quad \text{ for all large } k
\end{align}

To get an idea of what's going on and to suggest that this isn't totally impossible, consider the simpler problem where $b_k = 0$ for all $k$. In other words, suppose $K$ is allowed to be empty.
Then it is clear that $a_k = k^2$ satisfies (1),(2),(3),(4).

It seems intuitive to me that if we choose $b_k = 2c a_k - 100 \log a_k$ on a rapidly growing sequence $k = k_j$, and if we adjust $a_k$ a little bit when $k=k_j$, then we can still get (1),(2),(3),(4) to hold. But I am having a lot of trouble making this rigorous.

Edit: Cross-Posted from MathOverflow. It's been there for a while without progress. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/281862/proving-the-existence-of-a-sequence-with-recursive-growth-constraints

Comment: The third and fourth conditions seems to be contradicting.

Comment: When maximizing (4) one get that $a_k <(1-2c )^{-1} (a_{k-1} -2c a_{k-1})$, when minimizing (3) one get that $a_k > a_{k-1} +2c a_k$ so we get that $a_k < (1-2c)^{-1}(1-2c)(1-2c)a _k$ solving for $c$ yields that $c<0$ contradicting the assumption.

Comment: @Ahmad It seems like you are taking $K = \mathbb{Z}$. It clearly doesn't hold if $K = \mathbb{Z}$. But $K$ does not need to be $\mathbb{Z}$.